# PostgreSQL COPY command with csv file

Tags: postgresql, file-io, postgresql-copy

I have a csv file with two columns: `productId`, `productName`.
My table has the following columns: `productId`, `productName`, `productprice`.

I want to be able to copy this file into a Postgres table using the `COPY` command and at the same time set a value for a third column: `Productprice`.

`productPrice` is same for all rows. I use:

```
COPY product_master(productId, productName)
FROM 'product.txt' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```

I want to attach a price to all rows.

Comment: You want to .. what now? Attect?

Comment: You haven't specified how you want to the price to be derived. If it's constant (for now) then Erwin's answer will suffice, but you haven't given us enough to answer accurately.

Answer (score 3):

The remaining column will be filled in with the default, as the [manual tells us](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html):

> If there are any columns in the table that are not in the column list,
>   COPY FROM will insert the default values for those columns.

So, if the price is the same for all rows, create a column default.
Delete it afterwards, if you don't need it any more.

```
ALTER TABLE product_master ALTER COLUMN productrice SET DEFAULT 12.5;
COPY ...
ALTER TABLE product_master ALTER COLUMN productrice DROP DEFAULT;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a high level solution to importing data as such is your question.

There're a few ways to do this, but I normally always use a staging table when moving data into a database system. Such as product_master_stg which can be very generic such as it might have column types all set to text and null or you can get more specific and match the data types to the expected file columns types.  After using copy to get the data into staging I write a stored function to extract the data from the staging table and transform and load it into the target table at this point you can calculate your productprice value.  This lends itself well to varying requirements with the the main downside being a call to a stored function to get it to your final table, but everything has some cost associated with it so don't consider this a bad cost.  If you constantly follow this approach it will scale well and is very logical to use and maintain.